# Programmatically change iPhone Background

Tags: iphone

is it possible to change the iPhone background from code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you write a new png to `/User/Library/LockBackground.png` and then call `notify_post(" com.apple.language.changed");` the device will respring and your new background will be present.

This isn't technically a private API, but does fall outside of what Apple allows on the store.

Answer (score 7):

Nope, you can only save a picture for the user to set as a background.

Comment: what if the user sets a background image and I'll dynamically change it?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't overwrite photos either.
Check rpetrichs answer for a possible solution, but as he said, it won't work on the appstore.

Answer (score 2):

Mel is correct, there's no way to skip over the save process.

The reason this will always be the case:

Apple doesn't want apps to be able to set the background immediately upon opening. Theoretically, they could have a permission box (like the location dialog), but I doubt that will happen anytime soon.