# Is it still being prohibited changing lock screen(wallpaper) in iPhone OS 3.x?

Tags: iphone, lockscreen

I checked [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717535/programatically-change-iphone-background), so it was impossible to do it.
But it's old posting, and somebody are saying me there is an app which can change wallpaper(lock screen). Is this allowed now?

-- edit --

I'm sorry for my question was unclear.
I was asked a programmatic and regular (which can be approved by Apple AppStore) way to change lock-screen wallpaper in my own app.

Not for any hacked, jail-breaken devices.

Comment: Are you asking if an App can do it? Or just you want to change your wallpaper on your phone? Is the phone jail-broken? Unless your asking about how to get an App to do it, I'd move this to
 http://superuser.com
. If you do have an app in mind, my question would be can the app prompt the user to unlock the screen lock Spyker mentions, or if the app just has to come with instructions on how the user can do it on their own before using the app.

Comment: I'm sorry for my unclear question. I modified question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you would not be able to change the wallpaper for the device through the SDK, or at least not in a way in which Apple would approve of.  I suspect allowing this through the SDK could cause problems, apps could obnoxiously add advertisements to the wallpaper, etc.

The only way I can think of around your problem would be to save the target image to the user's camera roll and instruct the user to change it for themselves.

There may be a way to change the wallpaper for a jailbroken device, but this of course violates the iPhone developer program license agreement.

Comment: All apps that I've seen which allow modification of the lock screen seem to do exactly what Jamie is mentioning here.   For now this appears to be the only way to do it...   that is, to save the image to the user's camera roll and then tell them to go and change it themselves. 

I use a simple to-do manager called "Done" that does this if you want to see it in action. http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/done/id300799754?mt=8